# Como utilizar o request do make:request Laravel para poder limpar o controller

Tags: laravel, validação

Laravel 5.5
Estou usando as validações da seguinte maneira, diretamente no controller

```
$this->validate($req,[
        'nome' => 'required|min:10',
        'cpf' => 'required|size:14',
        'agencia' => 'required',
    ],[
        'nome.required'=>'Preencha um nome',
        'nome.min'=>'Campo nome: Minimo de 10 Caracteres',
        'cpf.size' => 'Preencha corretamente o CPF',
        'required' => 'Campo Necessário',
    ]);
```

E nas views estão ou em lista ou nos campo inputs as mensagens de erros:

```
@if(count($errors) > 0 )
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
  @endif
```

Gostaria de saber como utilizar o make:request e colocar nas funções de rules e messages pois quando eu coloco, ao submeter o formulário ocorre erro de autenticação
no controller de salvar coloco a request e importo a mesma

```
public function salvar(TesteValidaRequest $req){...}
```

no arquivo da request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'nome' => 'required|min:10'
    ];
}
public function messages()
{
return [
    'nome.required' => 'Necessário preencher um nome',
    'nome.min'  => 'Nome minimp de 10 Caracteres',
];
```

A dúvida é de que está aparecendo erro de ação não autorizada ao submeter o formulario, mesmo o authorize() retornando falso como fala na documentação, e também gostaria de saber se para passar os erros para as views é da mesma maneira, tentei através da documentação e não consegui.

Comment: o `authorize` tem que ser `true` para você conseguir utilizar; com relação à exibição de erros o jeito que você esta fazendo é o mais recomendado mesmo.

Comment: da maneira direta no controller está totalmente funcional, mas gostaria de colocar nas requests, como informa na documentação que limpa o codigo da controller.

Comment: Você criou o método public function authorize() { return true; } no TesteValidaRequest? Se este método retornar false que é o padrão, você não vai conseguir submeter.

Comment: Obrigado! funcionou agora com a alteração do método para true.

Answer (score 0):

o método `authorize` na sua classe `TesteValidaRequest` precisa retornar `true` para que você possa utilizar essa classe como validadora.

```
public function authorize() {
    return true;
}
```